# Unable to import module even after adding __init__.py

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask application and I have the following directory structure:

```
flask_app/
|
|-- __init__.py
|-- app.py
|-- views.py
|-- static/
|-- templates/
```

Example contents of the files are:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import views

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

views.py:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"a
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty.

When I run the application, the server starts, but the index page 404's. I understand that I need an `__init__.py` file for imports to work, so is the views.py file not being imported ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a circular import. When `app.py` imports `views`, the processing of `app.py` pauses while `views.py` processes. The first thing `views.py` does is import `app` from `app.py`, but `app` hasn't been defined yet, so `app.py` is imported. This pauses the processing of `views.py` and begins processing `app.py`. Etc.

The [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) provides a solution to this.

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask

flask = Flask(__name__)

import views

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`views.py`

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"
```

EDIT: Looking into the flask documentation, adding a `run.py` to the directory above `flask_app` and renaming app.py to `__init__.py` results in the problem being solved.

`run.py`

```
from yourapplication import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

The directory structure is now as follows:

```
|run.py
|flask_app/
|
|-- __init__.py
|-- app.py
|-- views.py
|-- static/
|-- templates/
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I had to create a separate run.py file in the directory above `flask_blog` and rename `app.py` to `__init__.py` for it to work, but at the end it did. Can you edit your answer to reflect the small change ?

Answer (score 0):

Code inside if_name==main will be executed in case this file has been run as script, not imported.

Here is how it works for me:

structure:

-> calculator (project folder)

---->calculator (package folder)

-------->_ _init___.py

--------> views.py

--------> createdb.py

---->runserver.py

**init**.py script

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(DEBUG=True)

import createdb
import views
```

runserver.py script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from calculator import app

app.run()
```

and application is run via command line by calling *runserver.py*